# Text bottom + center UILabel iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

I have created an iOS application using Swift. Now I have one issue I want to make my text center + bottom in one label and center + top in another label. Is it possible to do?

I tried this

```
//Here learnItem is my label.
     let constraintSize: CGSize = CGSizeMake(learnItem.frame.size.width, CGFloat(MAXFLOAT))
     let textRect: CGRect = learnItem.text!.boundingRectWithSize(constraintSize, options: .UsesLineFragmentOrigin, attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: learnItem.font], context: nil)
            learnItem.drawRect(textRect);
```

It doesn't affect anything. So maybe it is a wromg code. Also I saw

```
learnItem.textAlignment = .Center
```

There is option for `center, justified, left, natural, right`. But that is not what I want.

Please some one help me **how to make my text center + bottom and center + top**?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In order to do this you should override `drawTextInRect` method.

```
// MARK: - BottomAlignedLabel

@IBDesignable class BottomAlignedLabel: UILabel {

    // MARK: Lifecycle

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    override func drawText(in rect: CGRect) {

        guard text != nil else {
            return super.drawText(in: rect)
        }

        let height = self.sizeThatFits(rect.size).height
        let y = rect.origin.y + rect.height - height
        super.drawText(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: y, width: rect.width, height: height))
    }
}
```

For top alignment `y` should be `0`.

If you're using storyboard the easiest way to use this code is just change class for your label in storyboard.

Comment: I forgot to mention I also saw this code. And don't know how to use it. If I add this how can I connect this with my label. Maybe stupid question. But don't know how doing it?

Comment: The easiest way is to change class of your label in storyboard to `BottomAlignedLabel `

Comment: Thanks man. From yesterday onward I was looking this exact code. Thanks to help me to figured out.

Comment: Please update your answer to  this. "The easiest way is to change class of your label in storyboard to BottomAlignedLabel". Maybe it will help someone.